# When should I design my UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a ViewController which has a method to design the UINavigationBar, a SubViewController which inherits from the ViewController and calls its designing method and a ShowingViewController  and a SecondViewController which inherit from the SubViewController.

The ShowingViewController is the root controller of a UINavigationController and performs a "Show" Segue to the SecondViewController.
They have both the NSString property "presentingProperty".
The ViewController sets a custom titelView to the navigation bar which shows the property string.

My Question: Where should I call the designing method of ViewController?

When I call it in viewWillLoad, I won't work when I switch to SecondViewController because the method changes the NavigationBar of the "old" ShowingViewController.

When I call it in viewDidLoad, the user will see the undesigned NavigationBar before.

Code of my designing method:

```
if (self.navigationController.navigationBar) {
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21)];
    NSMutableAttributedString *titleText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.presentingProperty];
    [titleText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor whiteColor] range: NSMakeRange(0, self.presentingProperty.length)];
    [titleText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:21] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.presentingProperty.length)];
    [titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [titleLabel setAttributedText: titleText];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:titleLabel];
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      self.navigationItem.titleView = <your titleView>
}
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
     <your titleView>.frame = CGRectMake(....)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set up the titleView for a navigationBar in:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    <your titleView code here>
}
```

This is called after *viewDidLoad* on the first time, and is called later when other ViewControllers above the current one are popped off the navigation stack. A good state diagram of the ViewController life cycles can be found in the docs at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#1652793

On a point of style, you can also set the titleView with this code:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = <your-view>;
```